# Plot an AltAz grid over a square grid of RADec points

Tags: python, astropy

first post here.  As I'm new, StackExchange won't let create or use the wcsaxes tag.  wcsaxes looks like the most appropriate tool for the job, but astropy is closely related.

I think the title says it all, but I'll give a little more detail.  I have a bunch of sources in (RA, Dec) and want to plot them in the simplest possible projection (i.e. square, but if this is not possible we can make allowances).  I want to see the geometry of the Earth over my region of interest, mostly to identify the Earth's magnetic field lines.

The following code gets me close, but I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_geodetic'
```

If I change "altaz" to "galactic", I get a Galactic coordinates grid over the points, which is what I want, but obviously in the wrong coordinate frame.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import numpy as np
from astropy.wcs import WCS
from astropy.time import Time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# time = Time(2606629, format="jd", location=("116.670810d", "-26.756528d")).iso
w = WCS(naxis=2)
w.wcs.ctype = ["RA---MER", "DEC--MER"]
# w.wcs.dateavg = time

ra_min = 0
ra_max = 15
dec_min = -45
dec_max = -15
N = 1000

sim_ra  = np.random.uniform(ra_min, ra_max, size=N)
sim_dec = np.random.uniform(dec_min, dec_max, size=N)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.9, 0.9], projection=w)
overlay = ax.get_coords_overlay('altaz')

overlay[0].set_ticks(color='white')
overlay[1].set_ticks(color='white')
overlay[0].set_axislabel('Longitude')
overlay[1].set_axislabel('Latitude')
overlay.grid(color='black', linestyle='solid', alpha=0.5)

plt.scatter(sim_ra, sim_dec)
plt.xlabel('RA')
plt.ylabel('Dec')
plt.show()
```

I played a little with trying to get the observation time into the WCS header (note that the actual time is artificial, but should work regardless), without success.  Any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked into pyephem?

Comment: I noticed that stackoverflow.com has over 350 questions each for both `astropy` and `pyephem`.

Comment: Note that stellarium will display an overlay of AltAz and RADec grids, and that the "north" here is the Earth's rotational north pole, not the Earth's magnetic north pole.